# add mail to function to the mail id

Tags: php, html

In my site I have added this following code to retrieve the mail id from the backend:

```
<li><i class="icon-mail"></i><span><?php _e('Email:','directory');?> <?php echo cs_allow_special_char($cs_email);?></span></li>
```

But this code is not showing me the on click feature in the mail id. I am adding this code to make the link clickable:

```
<li><i class="icon-mail"></i><span><?php _e('Email:','directory');?> <a href="mailto:<?php echo cs_allow_special_char($cs_email);?>><?php echo cs_allow_special_char($cs_email);?></a></span></li>
```

But it is not working for me. Can someone please check the code and correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: You're missing a `"`: `<a href="mailto:<?php echo cs_allow_special_char($cs_email);?>">`

Comment: Thanks, its working.

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest to get familiar with the Browser Console (F12) to see the HTML as the browser interprets it.